# SOLVED - Knitr/pandoc bibliography problem

Tags: bibliographies, knitr, pandoc

I would try to convert the way I write my scientific articles from Sweave/LaTeX to knitr/pandoc. I've been able to reproduce almost everithing with the exceptions of the references. I googled a lot and I read the official and unofficial guide to the pandoc references but I've not yet found the right solution to my problem: no citations are included in my document.

This is what I've done:

1. added bibliography: myBib.bib to the header of the file
2. added the citation using `[@KEY]`, where KEY is the key entry in my
   .bib file
3. added `# References` section at the bottom of my document
4. convert .Rmd file to .md file using knitr
5. from shell I run:

   pandoc -H headers.tex --bibliography=myBib.bib -o
       article.pdf article.md

The .pdf file was generated but with non citation references

I've also tried to generate the .tex file and then to compile it `pandoc --bibliography=myBib.bib -o article.tex article.md` also using the `--natbib` and `--biblatex` switch, but nothing changes. Opening the .tex file I noticed that the citations were converted as: `{[}@01, @46{]}` while in the .md file I wrote: [@01, @46]. Could be this the issue?

I work using debian jessie, pandoc 1.12.4.2, knitr 1.11, emacs24.

**EDIT 24 Aug 2015**

Seems that all the problems were due to the old package in the stable and backport Debian repos. Now I installed pandoc and pandoc-citeproc from [source](http://pandoc.org/installing.html#installing-from-source) and all seems to work properly. I will inform the debian administrators of the malfunction in the version present in the repositories.

Comment: Does it work if you write [@01; @46]? I think references need to be separated with semicolons rather than commas.

Comment: By the way, you're a few releases behind on Pandoc so it might be a good idea to upgrade unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: @Tom: I tried using both semicolon and commas but nothing change. I use the pandoc version in the debian stable repo.

Comment: That's a good reason not to upgrade.

Comment: The output you see is what Pandoc produces when it can't find a bibliography file. I noticed in your post that in step 1 you call the file 'SoilVOCs.bib' and when you describe what you're doing in the shell you call it 'myBib.bib'. Is the difference a typo and you're actually calling Pandoc with the right file name?

Comment: Does it help to add --filter=pandoc-citeproc? I think that the latest versions of Pandoc set it implicitly when you use --bibliography, but I don't know whether that was introduced between 1.12 and now.

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: I'm puzzled then. Doing what you're doing works for me using the latest version on OS X. You could try asking on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pandoc-discuss if you haven't already.

Comment: I edited the post. Installing the latest pandoc all works fine. The problems I have had are due to a prevous version(1.12.4.2)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was due to outdated software and the question includes the solution so there's no question now.